# How to open a Slick Carousel to a specific slide in modal from a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have an array of thumbnails and a Slick Carousel in modal (obviously, it is hidden by default). How can I open that carousel by clicking on a thumbnail so that it would start from the corresponding slide?

[image: An array of thumbnails]

Answer (score 0):

In your question there are two points

1. How to initialize a carousel in a modal
2. How to start the slide from a specific slide

Let me take an example with bootbox modal(Most of the modals work in the same way),  You can initialize the carousel in the shown modal callback.

You can use `initialSlide` property of the slickSlider to start from a specific slide.

```
var box = bootbox.dialog({
    message: 'This is some HTML content inside modal(e.g, .html() of carousel)'
});

box.on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $('.slick-carousel').slick({
        initialSlide: indexOfThumbnail // indexOfThumbnail needs to be initialized before
    });
});
```